# How to use lapply to get the mean of a specific column in all dataframes of the list?

Tags: r, mean, lapply

I have a list with 160 dataframes, that all have the same structure. Every dataframe corresponds to one country

```
Afghanistan <- data.frame(seq(1970, 2010, 10), c(20,30,30,40,10))
Albania <- data.frame(seq(1970, 2010, 10), c(10, 40, NA, 50, 20))
colnames(Afghanistan) <- (c("Year", "Value"))
colnames(Albania) <- (c("Year", "Value"))
List1 <- list(Afghanistan, Albania)
```

Every Dataframe's structure looks like this:

```
Year    Value
1970    20
1980    30
1990    30
2000    40
2010    10
```

How can I get the mean of the column "Value" for each dataframe in the list. I tried to use the lapply function, but I couldn't figure out how to do it correctly. This didn't work:

```
lapply(List1[[]][,2], mean, na.rm = T)
```

Or would it be better to union all dataframes to one single big dataframe and then use aggregate to get the mean for every country?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: `lapply(ListName, function(df) mean(df[,2]))`? I'm with MrFlick, though, it is much better (and preferred) to include relevant (but simplified) sample data with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list like this:

```
my_list <- list(data.frame(year = c(2000:2003),
                           value = c(1:4)),
                data.frame(year = c(2000:2003),
                           value = c(5:8)))
```

You can use `lapply()` to loop through that list. Each `x` is the a `data.frame` and you can access columns using `$`:

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) {
  mean(x$value)
})
```

This will return

```
[[1]]
[1] 2.5

[[2]]
[1] 6.5
```

UPDATE after edit:

```
lapply(List1, function(x) {
  mean(x$Value, na.rm = TRUE)
})
```

Returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] 26

[[2]]
[1] 30
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I missunderstood the functioning of lapply. Now I think it's clear to me.

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad it works! If you want, you can accept the answer to show your question was answered.